# The process was terminated due to stack overflow error on one server not another

Tags: .net, asynchronous, stack-overflow

we are getting the above error when our web service is called on a particular server but not on another. Here is the code that is used....

```
foreach (Service service in serviceSetup.Services)
{
    if (service.CallService == true)
    {
        serviceConfig = ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration(service.Name, service.URL);
        aSyncRequest = new ASyncRequest(serviceConfig.GetEnrichmentXML);
        IAsyncResult res = aSyncRequest.BeginInvoke(request, null, null);
        results.Add(res);
        waitHandles.Add(res.AsyncWaitHandle);
    }
}

bool terminExists = false; 
if (waitHandles.Count > 0)
{
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles.ToArray(), Convert.ToInt32(Utils.AppSetting("ServiceWaitTime")));

    foreach (IAsyncResult res in results)
    {
        if (res.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                returnEnrichmentXML = aSyncRequest.EndInvoke(res);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnEnrichmentXML.ABIQ))
                {
                    //need to see if we insert or concat the return enriched data as skinny can be done locally in electRa
                    //prior to QuotesHub 
                    int index = enrichmentXML.ABIQ.IndexOf("99TERMIN|");
                    if (index > -1)
                    {
                        enrichmentXML.ABIQ = enrichmentXML.ABIQ.Insert(index, returnEnrichmentXML.ABIQ);
                        terminExists = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enrichmentXML.ABIQ = string.Concat(enrichmentXML.ABIQ, returnEnrichmentXML.ABIQ);
                        enrichmentABIQAdded = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnEnrichmentXML.FullResults))
                {
                    enrichmentXML.FullResults = string.Concat(enrichmentXML.FullResults, returnEnrichmentXML.FullResults);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No i have just thought that i may not be calling EndInvoke on results that are not completed. So i presume .NET would store this in memory until the GC would clear it up. I don't think this would cause a stack overflow issue though.

We also get the issue even if just one asynchronous call is made. I'm not a massive server expert either, but the server it is working on is a lot worse than the one it isn't working on.

Any ideas??

Cheers

Comment: There's quite a lot of code above; can you indicate which line is throwing the `StackOverflowException` when it occurs?

Comment: I always love it when a stack overflow error is raised on stack overflow ..... Are you sure that your servers are identical? If you have a problem on one and not another, the implication is that the server environment is different ( not necessarily wrong, but the difference may point to where the problem actually is )

Comment: See if one of `service.URL` being looped through points back to the server that gets the stack overflow.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't actually throw an exception, it creates n error in the event log with that description.